# NetBeans file upload config

Tags: netbeans

Is there a way to stop the confirmation window from opening with the files checked and then having to click ok for the file to upload?

I set up a shortcut on the keyboard to upload, and I just want to use the shortcut and have it upload without me having to click anything.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I have been using stable and development versions on linux. Now NetBeans IDE 7.0 M2 (Build 201010151251).

I've noticed that development versions never ask for confirmation to upload. Thats good but dangerous. So I set up a shortcut away from the usual combinations like [CTRL][L].